# Did this return a reference or a new object?

Tags: java, methods, reference-type

The object Carta, has two string fields: "Cara" and "Palo"
a constructor like:

```
public Carta(String a, String b){Cara = a, Palo = b}
```

and a modified toString method:

```
public String toString(){return Cara+" de "+Palo}
```

so if i do this:

```
Carta[] arreglo = {new Carta("a","b") , new Carta("c","d"), new Carta("f","g"), new Carta("h","i") };

Carta abs = arreglo[0];
System.out.println(abs);

arreglo = Arrays.copyOfRange(arreglo,1,arreglo.length);

System.out.println(abs);
```

Why do i get this output:

```
a de b 
a de b
```

i thought abs was only a reference to the first element of the array arreglo

Comment: You've said `System.out.println(abs);` twice.  What was it *supposed* to do?

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code

```
Carta abs = arreglo[0];
```

stores the reference to the object at index 0 of the `arreglo` array in the variable `abs`. If you then change the element in the array, the `abs` variable is still referencing the previous object.

This

```
System.out.println(abs);
```

prints the first element and you do

```
System.out.println(abs);
```

again which prints it again.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do i get this output:
>
> ```
> a de b
> a de b
> ```
>
> i thought abs was only a reference to the first element of the array arreglo.

`abs` it's a reference to the `Carta` instance. Not to the array `arreglo`. So as you don't modify that instance `abs` still is the same object state.  What you are doing is assigning to reference `arreglo` a new array.